# Rails 4 + ReactJS: "SyntaxError: cannot have an implicit value in an implicit object"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, reactjs

I am following Fernando Villalobos' *[React.js - A guide for Rails developers](https://www.airpair.com/reactjs/posts/reactjs-a-guide-for-rails-developers)* AirPair tutorial.

The goal here is to build a simple expense tracking app, using Rails and React JS.

In the [*Nesting Components: Listing Records*](https://www.airpair.com/reactjs/posts/reactjs-a-guide-for-rails-developers#nesting-components-listing-records) section, the author recommends to create a `app/views/records/index.html.erb` file as follows:

```
<%# app/views/records/index.html.erb %>
<%= react_component 'Records', { data: @records } %>
```

AND a `javascripts/components/records.js.coffee` file as follows:

```
# app/assets/javascripts/components/records.js.coffee

  @Records = React.createClass
    render: ->
      React.DOM.div
        className: 'records'
        React.DOM.h2
          className: 'title'
          'Records'
```

Then, when we visit `localhost:3000/records`, we are supposed to see the following:

[image]

However, when I visit `localhost:3000/records`, I get the following error:

```
ExecJS::RuntimeError in Records#index
SyntaxError: [stdin]:7:10: cannot have an implicit value in an implicit object
<title>Expenses</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
```

In particular, the line causing the issue seems to be:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

Any idea of what the probelm is and how I can make things work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following coffescript instead of your current coffescript(Just removing `React.DOM` from the coffescript):

```
@Records = React.createClass
  render: ->
    div
      className: 'records'
      h2
        className: 'title'
        'Records'
```

Comment: The problem was coming from the indentation. I just posted an answer to explain that. But, as usual, thanks a lot for your help and your responsiveness, it is highly appreciated.

Comment: No problem, yeah, that was from coffescript compilation problem. I found some suggestion without using `React.DOM` in react version .12 so thought that would be the issue. Because, I tried your coffescript code here: http://www.coffeelint.org/ and it did not complaint. Anyways, I am glad its working for you now :)

Answer (score 6):

My mistake.

I was using Ruby "two-space" indentation in my CoffeeScript file, which caused the error.

When I copied and pasted the code from the tutorial, with the right indentation, everything worked like a charm.

Comment: Thanks -- same error here.  Renews the debate on white space being significant!