# How do you render HTML tags in React with Coffeescript?

Tags: reactjs, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm currently learning ReactJS and how to work with Ruby on Rails as its backend, so I apologize if I'm making dumb assumptions, feel free to scold me.

I'm following a tutorial where the author is using Coffeescript instead of ES6 to handle his ReactJS code.

He provides an example component similar to this (coffeescript):

```
@Rows = React.createClass
  render ->
    React.DOM.div
      className: 'rows'
      React.DOM.h1
        className: 'title'
        'Rows'
```

This has two errors. The first one pertains to `React.createClass` which I found out has been deprecated and no longer works. Instead I'm using `createReactClass`. Good. But now, `React.DOM.h1` gives an error saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'h1' of undefined`, same for whichever other HTML tag I use. I assume it's due to `createReactClass` not providing the necessary functionality previously provided by `React.createClass`.

Anyway, while researching for another error indirectly related to this, [I found someone suggesting to use something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32318375/3209270):

```
@Rows = React.createClass
  render ->
    div
      className: 'rows'
      h1
        className: 'title'
        'Rows'
```

So, cutting off the `React.DOM` part. This gives another type of error, saying: `Uncaught ReferenceError: div is not defined`.  Again, I'm assuming it's due to the change to `React.createClass`.

Is there a way to use React with CoffeeScript, such that I could use it like this:

```
@Rows = createReactClass
  render ->
    div
      className: 'rows'
      h1
        className: 'title'
        'Rows'
```

without having to open and close HTML tags, and without `React.DOM`?

I don't know if it's possible at all, or if it ever worked, or even if there're many ways to achieve something with similar results. I'm just curious to know if there's a way to do it like this before I dive deeper onto React.

Thanks!

## Update

I've made some progress, though I'm still getting an error. I tried the following:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDom from 'react-dom'
{div, h1, p} = ReactDom

class Rows extends React.Component
  render: ->
    h1
      className: 'col-md-12'
      'Rows'
  
export default Rows
```

This gives the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: h1 is not a function`.

Comment: official documentation gives you the required information http://coffeescript.org/v2/#jsx

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, they only mention the XML elements, which have to be enclosed with both an opening and a closing tag. My question is about using them like in my third code snippet (no closing tags, just indentation, coffeescript style).

Comment: To write using jsx-like syntax see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61615873/how-to-use-react-within-rails-using-coffee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what finally worked

```
React = require('react')
PropTypes = require('prop-types')
ReactDom = require('react-dom-factories')
createReactClass = require('create-react-class')
{div, h1} = ReactDom

Rows = createReactClass
  render: ->
    div
      className: 'col-md-12'
      h1
        className: 'title'
        'Rows'

export default Rows
```

So I've been using React 16 and it's incredible how many things have changed in the last 6 months. I'm TOTALLY new to React, so I had absolutely no idea how this worked, but I managed to use the code above without errors.

**First**:

```
ReactDom = require('react-dom-factories')
```

This is the one I was missing. I was getting errors that `div` and `h1` weren't functions, or weren't defined. So it turns out that [per the documentation](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html) `React.DOM` is now available as `react-dom-factories`:

> The deprecations introduced in 15.x have been removed from the core
>   package. React.createClass is now available as create-react-class,
>   React.PropTypes as prop-types, React.DOM as react-dom-factories,
>   react-addons-test-utils as react-dom/test-utils, and shallow renderer
>   as react-test-renderer/shallow.

**Second**:

If anyone else runs onto this and you get errors that say `Cannot find module "react-dom-factories"`, it means you have to add them to your webpacker with this:

```
yarn add react-dom-factories
```

You may also have to add `create-react-class` and `prop-types`, if you're following my example above.

**Lastly:**

Be sure the extension of your coffeescript file is simply .coffee. If you use `.js.coffee` or `.jsx.coffee` you'll get errors that the component cannot be found.

<strike>I'm not 100% sure if this is necessary, but I also added `cjsx-loader` to my webpacker when I was searching for a solution. It's a coffee-react-transform loader module for Webpack.</strike>

**UPDATE**: This last part wasn't necessary. I made a new project and this wasn't required at all.

Answer (score 3):

You can use coffeescript with React without JSX. I think it makes for much cleaner code:

```
React = require('react')
ReactDOM = require('react-dom')
{div, h1} = ReactDom


class Rows extends React.Component

  render: ->
    div
      className: 'rows'
      h1
        className: 'title'
        'Rows'

module.exports = React.createFactory Rows
```

1. Depending on the version of React you are using, you may need to separately include the [React-DOM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dom) package
2. [Destructure](http://coffeescript.org/#destructuring) `ReacDom` to use the DOM elements directly
3. Use the class syntax of Coffeescript instead of the legacy functions.
4. Export a factory of your component so you can easily use it in another component:

```
 Rows = require('./rows')

 class OtherComponent extends React.Component
   .
   .
   .
   render: ->
     div
       className: 'container'
       Rows()
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do! Now, forgive my noob question, I'm getting that `require` is not defined. What could I be missing? I can run a "standard" component in JSX format (with different code, of course), so I'm thinking the issue is not on my `application.js`.

Comment: I updated my question with some progress I made with the help you provided. I'm still getting an error, but I think I'm getting closer.