# How to use React within Rails using coffee?

Tags: reactjs, coffeescript, webpacker

I'm adding Reactjs on a Rails application (5.2), but I want to use coffeescript to write it. I've added webpack and installed react and coffee support, and both seems to work, but when I want to use both I get:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:9)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/coffee-loader/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|
| Foo = props(() => {
>   return <div>Hello {props.name}!</div>;
| });
|
```

I also updated coffeescript to the version 2.0 that should support jsx natively. What could I be missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you render HTML tags in React with Coffeescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47464686/how-do-you-render-html-tags-in-react-with-coffeescript)

Comment: @caffeinated.tech It is a solution, but it does not use jsx that should be supported with coffeescript 2 (and is used a lot with React so I would use it if possible).

Comment: Can you share your webpacker config? You're right - it should be possible, but I think the configuration is rather tricky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally made it work, the problem is that (as @caffeinated.tech mentioned) the configuration is rather tricky.

The required steps to make it work where:

- Add coffeescript version 2 to the dependencies (by default webpacker installs the version 1).
- Make sure coffeescript loader is appended to the loader (it is [prepended by default](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/lib/install/coffee.rb#L12)):

```js
// config/webpack/environment.js

const coffee =  require('./loaders/coffee')

// instead of environment.loaders.prepend('coffee', coffee)
environment.loaders.append('coffee', coffee)
/// ...
```

- And configure [coffee-loader to transpile](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/coffee-loader/#transpile):

```js
// config/webpack/loaders/coffee.js
module.exports = {
  test: /\.coffee(\.erb)?$/,
  use: [{
    loader: 'coffee-loader',
    options: {
      transpile: {} // it seems that transpile options can be used here,
                    // but I couldn't find what to use
    }
  }]
}
```

### Update

Instead of configuring coffee to transpile (as mentioned before), in [this issue](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/993#issuecomment-360183127) it does recommend configuring babel loader to not ignore coffee files (it does not process coffee files [on the default config](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/package/rules/babel.js#L9))

```js
// config/webpack/environment.js

// Make babel process coffee files
environment.loaders.get('babel').test = /\.(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx|coffee)?(\.erb)?$/
```

After that it does work.